# replacing multiple table information in mysql

Tags: mysql

I've recently been given the task of maintaining a sports team's website and have encountered a problem which I cannot find the answer.

It uses Nucleus CMS which is fine and I'm used to it, unfortunately, the domain name has changed and all links and files within the site stored in the mysql database are now out of date and not the correct one.

I am able to manually alter each item using the admin panel of the CMS, but with several thousand posts, that task is daunting.

Is there a way I can do a "replace" domain1.com to domain2.com in the item table in one process through the mysql database?

Forgive me if I'm not using the correct terminology.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE tbl SET domain_name = 'domain2.com' WHERE domain_name = 'domain1.com';
```